# elf.h: No such file or directory when using the x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc cross-compiler

Tags: operating-system, cross-compiling, mingw32

I have been told by many developers to use a cross-compiler to compile my Operating System.
The issue is when I switched from using `gcc` to using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`, it gave me the error in the title of this post.

I am on Windows using WSL, and I checked `/usr/include` to see if `elf.h` was there, and it was. So I tried including that directory when compiling using `-I/usr/include` and it still did not work.

PS: I am trying to call my `__main` function inside kernel.cpp, and I need `elf.h` to get the header entry (unless there is a way to do it without `elf.h` that I don't know about).

Full Bootloader Makefile:

```
all:
    x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Ignu-efi/inc -Ignu-efi/inc/x86_64 -Ignu-efi/inc/protocol -c -o build/main.o c/main.c
    x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Ignu-efi/inc -Ignu-efi/inc/x86_64 -Ignu-efi/inc/protocol -c -o build/data.o gnu-efi/lib/data.c
    x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -nostdlib -Wl,-dll -shared -Wl,--subsystem,10 -e efi_main -o essentials/main.efi build/main.o build/data.o
```

I am using UEFI Bare Bones (GNU-EFI Headers only).

Is there a way to stop the error, or is there an alternative to using `elf.h`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding the structs manually to my `main.c` file:

```
typedef uint64_t Elf64_Addr;

#define ELFMAG      "\177ELF"
#define SELFMAG     4
#define EI_CLASS    4       /* File class byte index */
#define ELFCLASS64  2       /* 64-bit objects */
#define EI_DATA     5       /* Data encoding byte index */
#define ELFDATA2LSB 1       /* 2's complement, little endian */
#define ET_EXEC     2       /* Executable file */
#define PT_LOAD     1       /* Loadable program segment */
#ifdef __x86_64__
#define EM_MACH     62      /* AMD x86-64 architecture */
#endif
#ifdef __aarch64__
#define EM_MACH     183     /* ARM aarch64 architecture */
#endif


typedef struct
{
    uint8_t  e_ident[16];   /* Magic number and other info */
    uint16_t e_type;        /* Object file type */
    uint16_t e_machine;     /* Architecture */
    uint32_t e_version;     /* Object file version */
    uint64_t e_entry;       /* Entry point virtual address */
    uint64_t e_phoff;       /* Program header table file offset */
    uint64_t e_shoff;       /* Section header table file offset */
    uint32_t e_flags;       /* Processor-specific flags */
    uint16_t e_ehsize;      /* ELF header size in bytes */
    uint16_t e_phentsize;   /* Program header table entry size */
    uint16_t e_phnum;       /* Program header table entry count */
    uint16_t e_shentsize;   /* Section header table entry size */
    uint16_t e_shnum;       /* Section header table entry count */
    uint16_t e_shstrndx;    /* Section header string table index */
} Elf64_Ehdr;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t p_type;        /* Segment type */
    uint32_t p_flags;       /* Segment flags */
    uint64_t p_offset;      /* Segment file offset */
    uint64_t p_vaddr;       /* Segment virtual address */
    uint64_t p_paddr;       /* Segment physical address */
    uint64_t p_filesz;      /* Segment size in file */
    uint64_t p_memsz;       /* Segment size in memory */
    uint64_t p_align;       /* Segment alignment */
} Elf64_Phdr;
```

Where I found these structs:
https://gitlab.com/bztsrc/posix-uefi/-/blob/master/examples/0F_exit_bs/exit_bs.c

If you have the file `elf.h` inside your `/usr/include` directory, you can also get these structs from that file.

You can copy the file to your preferred folder, like so:

```
cd some_dir/preferred_dir
cp /usr/include/elf.h .
```

And then copy the structs inside of it and paste them into your project.

If you are on Windows, you can use WSL to do this.

That is what I have learned.